# Problems installing vtk Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, vtk

I can't install vtk in python project with this command:

```
python -m pip install vtk
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: No matching distribution found for vtk
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vtk (from versions: none)
```

I tried to update my pip package :

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I tried to install the .whl file directly from the project directory:

```
python -m pip install .\vtk-9.1.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

I tried all vtk .whl file versions but I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: vtk-9.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

PS:  I use Python 3.10.0

Comment: what version of python do you use ?

Comment: `pip install vtk` worked for me on python 3.6.8, but not on 3.10.2. Still investigating

Comment: I'm using Python 3.10.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a problem that was [reported](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/issues/18335) 3 months ago. My recommendation is using python 3.9 for vtk, until it is resolved. I verified it works fine using python 3.9.10

Comment: **Yikes.** Doesn't exactly inspire confidence, does it? Python 3.11 is on the precipice of being stabilized. Meanwhile, VTK can't even support a Python version released over a year-and-a-half ago. `</gulp>`

Answer (score -1):

Hey if you are using python 3.7 or greater, then trying using this command:

```
pip3 install vtk
```

If you are using older versions, then try installing VTK from sources:
https://vtk.org/download/

Comment: `pip3 install vtk` is not working in python 3.10.0